# Is it better to have a sperate collections or one big collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We collect stats in min, hour and day basis and i was thinking is it better to have them in one collection (and have filed that describe what type they are) or to have three different collections (min, hour and day). Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stats collected by these 3 processes are similar(number/type of columns) and if you are going to process all the stats collected using same logic then you can store them in a same collection and have a type flag to differentiate and apply a sparse index on that flag.

Answer (score 0):

Depends completely on the kind of operations you do. If you are storing them for long time (months, so that count will be very high) and need  to show statistics as quickly as you can, i recommend storing them in 3 different collections so that you can show day statistics very quickly than hourly and minute stats.